# How do I configure a Wireguard Interface to connect to a remote peer through a specific network interface?

Tags: linux, networking, wireguard

Suppose I have two servers, `gateway` which is publicly visible to the internet and `appserver` which is hidden behind a nat/firewall. Also suppose that each of these two servers has *two* interfaces connected to entirely separate internet uplinks (see diagram bellow).

I want to set up two independent Wireguard tunnels between the two servers with the goal of keeping the servers connected if one of them fails:

```
                   |     Internet     |        
[ gateway ]        |                  |        [appserver]
                   |                  | 
   (wg0) <-----> (ens1) < - - - - > (ens1) <----> (wg0)
                   |                  | 
                   |                  | 
                   |                  |        
   (wg1) <-----> (ens2) < - - - - > (ens2) <----> (wg1)
                   |                  | 
                   |                  |
```

By default, Wireguard seems to route all traffic through the system's default gateway. So when `appserver` attempts to connect to `gateway`, it only uses one of the two interfaces:

```
                   |     Internet     |        
[ gateway ]        |                  |        [appserver]
                   |                  | 
   (wg0) <--+--> (ens1) < - - - - > (ens1) <--+--> (wg0)
            |      |                  |       |
            |      |                  |       |
            |      |                  |       | 
   (wg1) <--+    (ens2)      X      (ens2)    +--> (wg1)
                   |                  | 
                   |                  |
```

Since some network tools allow setting a specific network interface to use when sending network traffic, can Wireguard also do the same thing? That is, only send traffic over `ens1` or `ens2` regardless of default route metrics? If not, how can I set up Linux's networking systems to do this instead?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find a way to make wireguard itself connect through a specific interface, so I eventually settled on simply routing traffic destined to `ens2` by adding a new route to `appserver`'s routing tables:

```bash
ip route add $GATEWAY_ESN2_ADDR/32 via $APPSERVER_ESN2_ADDR_GW metric 50
```

`APPSERVER_ESN2_ADDR_GW` is the adddress of `appserver`'s gateway router.

While researching this, I noticed that wireguard allows you to set a fwmark on outgoing traffic belonging a specific wireguard interface by setting the `FwMark` field under `[Interface]`. Wireguard does not support setting this mark on a per-peer basis as of the time of this writing (2021-09).

*I'll be leaving this question open in case someone discovers a proper solution.